# HTML form submit button name tag empty

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two forms created in PHP as below

```
echo '<form name="delete" action="?page=deletetable" method="POST" autocomplete="off">';
    echo '<input type=submit value="Delete" name="'.$row['TableName'].'">';
echo "</form>"; 
echo '<form name="assign" action="?page=assign" method="POST" autocomplete="off">';
    echo '<select name="user">';
     $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE hasCustom = 0");
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['user_name']. "\">" . $row['user_name'] . "</option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";              
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Assign" name="'.$row['TableName'].'">';
echo "</form>";
```

This looks like the below in the end html code

```
<form name="delete" action="?page=deletetable" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <input type=submit value="Delete" name="rates_test">
</form>
<form name="assign" action="?page=assign" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <select name="user">
        <option value="zac">zac</option>
        <option value="testadmin">testadmin</option>
        <option value="tonyd">tonyd</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Assign" name="">
</form>
```

as you can see in the last submit button the name tag is empty yet in the first form the name tag is correct i.e `name="rates_test"`

Both forms are using the same PHP to get this value so I cant see why one works and the other does not.

Comment: Better use someother variable in the while instead of using `$row` itself.Because if your query didnt return then the value of `$row` will be empty.I suggest using someother varible name.

Comment: Sorry should have said @Deepu this is done within a while loop `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: Yeah thats wat i am talking about.`while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` use something like this and use `$rows` inside the while loop.So the variable `$row` wont be overwritted if your query returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a 'while' loop to reset $row. My guess is that ['TableName'] doesn't exist in $row after that loop.

Try using separate variable names for your first $row and the one in the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

With the line:

> while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

you overwrite the variable $row, try using a different variable for that while loop unless this is intended.

Answer (score 0):

`$row` variable is getting the new values again when you have fetched the records again from the query.

Try `($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))` instead of `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))`